# Laravel 5: How to find the id of a row based on another field?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a form in which the users should select a 'subject' for their projects.

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('subject', 'Subject', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
  {!! Form::select('subject',$subjects, null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

These subject are returned from a database table called 'subjects' with two columns, one for 'id' and one for 'subject'. The subject_id in the project table is referencing the id in subjects table. The user selects a subject name in the form but I need to the subject id to be saved in the project table. I want to modify this input in a form request and replace the subject by its id.
The function in the form request is like this:

```
public function prepInput(){
        $input=$this->all();
        $input['subject_id']=something;
        $this->replace($input);
    }
```

How can I find the id for a subject? I have a model for the subjects and the relations between this model and the project model are established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use eloquent [lists](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/easy-dropdowns-with-eloquents-lists-method)

Controller

```
$subjects = Subject::lists('subject', 'id');
```

View

```
{{ Form::select('subject', $subjects) }}
```

Comment: My problem is in the formrequest. How can I find the id in the 'prepInput()' ?

Comment: I'm kind of new to Laravel. Can you please explain more?